# Reduce openpose key points (skeleton) to detect minimal key point in openpose?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, openpose

I am using openpose Tensorflow for multi personal pose estimation. But as it follows COCO 18 keypoints detection, it is taking lots of time to detect. How can i reduce this detection of keypoints to detect only one part(eg: leg). means I don't want to detect full body. instead, I want to detect only legs with reduced keypoint numbers to increase the fps

I followed this tutorial:https://towardsdatascience.com/realtime-multiple-person-2d-pose-estimation-using-tensorflow2-x-93e4c156d45f

But I am getting an fps around 3. since it is detecting full-body, in my case it is a waste process, becoz 1 only want to detect one part(eg: leg) to increase the fps

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner of deep learning I will say there is not a easy way to revise it to detect only a single part.

If you are familiar with this it  you can change the `pafprocess` remove unused `parts` and recompile it, but actually I'm not sure about if you should retrain the model or not.

But I thought to use a lighter model is easier than change the code.